# How to display data value in real time without refreshing the page with PHP/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is a survey system. I have a dynamic dropdown that displays one column 'questiontitle' from my table database. How do I display its other columns 'Option_1 to Option_10' (I assumed the maximum options are 10), depending on the 'answer_type' column when it's clicked in real time without refreshing the page? Like if it the 'answer_type' is checkbox it will display it as checkbox and if it's radiobutton it will display radiobuttons. Here's my code of displaying the 'question_title' in the dropdown

```
  $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT question.* FROM question LEFT JOIN category AS subcategory on subcategory.category_id = question.question_subcat WHERE question.question_category = $question AND (question.question_subcat IS NULL OR subcategory.category_id IS NOT NULL)");
        echo "<b id='labelquestion_dropdown".$i."'>Question #". $i."</b>";
        echo "<select id='question_dropdown".$i."' class='form-control-static' name='question_dropdowns".$i."'>";
        echo "<option selected>"; echo "Select"; echo "</option>";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
                echo "<option value='$row[question_id]'>";
                echo $row["questiontitle"];
                echo "</option>";

        }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br />";
```

And here's my database table.
[image]

Comment: use ajax on this

Comment: Would you be able to assist with the code sir please? @Demonyowh

Comment: By using ajax call you are able to do this.

Comment: How to add an If else with ajax? I have to do an if else whether it's a radiobutton or checkbox. @ZaidBinKhalid

Comment: in the select option the user will select checkbox or radio button right?

Comment: Send an ajax call and check answer_type simple. If the answer_type is **checkbox** then on success show checkbox other wise show **radiobox**

Comment: Only the question_title is displayed on the select option. I want the answer type to be displayed with an if/else to determine if it's radiobutton or checkboox. @Exprator

Comment: ok do one thing. in the value section of the title post the id of the question and fire an ajax onselect of a option and get the query where it will get the answer type and display it. for that you need onselect jjquery for select box an ajax to get the id to the sql query and jquery to populate the result in some div or select box as you need

Answer (score 1):

Do some thing like this.

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php?id=<?php $row['id']; ?>',
        success:function(data){
            if(data){
                // do what ever you want to do
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**on AJAX.php**

First you get record against this id that you send in ajax url.

prepare your desired result

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax Technology then do this in your JS

```js
$(document).on('change','.dynamic-qst',function(){
    // ajax question possible answers or rather ajax your database where id = question id
    /* $.ajax({
             url: 'getPossibleAnswers.php',
             data: {id: $(this).val()},
             success: function(response){
                  //insert the var output = '';
                  // to $('#possible-ans').html(output);
             }
    }) */
    
    // assuming we had successfully ajax it and the response is
    // for question 1 example
    var response2 = {'answer_type':'checkbox', 'option_1':'Cellphone', 'option_2':'Computer', 'option_3':'Laptop', 'option_4':'', 'option_5':'', 'option_6':'', 'option_7':'', 'option_8':'', 'option_9':'', 'option_10':''};
    
    // for question 2 example
    var response = {'answer_type':'radio', 'option_1':'Sushi', 'option_2':'Maki', 'option_3':'Sashimi', 'option_4':'Teriyaki', 'option_5':'Misono', 'option_6':'', 'option_7':'', 'option_8':'', 'option_9':'', 'option_10':''};
    
    var output = '', x;
    for(x = 1; x <= 10 ; x++)
    {
        var cur_ans = eval("response.option_" + x);
        if(response.answer_type == 'checkbox')
        {
            if(cur_ans != '')
            {
                output += '<input type="checkbox" name="ans" value="' + cur_ans + '">' + cur_ans;
            }
        }
        else if(response.answer_type == 'radio')
        {
            if(cur_ans != '')
            {
                output += '<input type="radio" name="ans" value="' + cur_ans + '">' + cur_ans;
            }
        }
    }
    $('#possible-ans').html(output);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="dynamic-qst">
    <option value selected disabled>-- Select One --</option>
    <option value="1">What gadget do you usually use?</option>
    <option value="2">What is your favorite food?</option>
</select>

<div id="possible-ans"></div>
```

Comment: Sir the first output 'checkbox' isn't working on your snippet :( @demonyowh

Comment: it is because it's just a sample data .. if you use your real data it will work just fine ..

Comment: to see if it's working switch the two variable names .. change `response2` to `response` and vice versa ..

Comment: Sir mine is a dynamic dropdown that displays questiontitle. How do I implement the method? sry it's taking a while to digest I'm a native php user. @Demonyowh

Comment: well that's where ajax will help you .. ajax will help you fetch the question using the value of the dropdown .. script comment and it will help you ..

Comment: ok sir thank you this is my first time hearing ajax I will try to manage @Demonyoh